# Gateway timeout shown

Tags: bug, advertising

Just as an fyi, as shown below where AdChoices normally shows in the sidebar in stackoverflow.com, I'm seeing a 504 gateway timeout error.

[image: here]

Comment: That's not AdChoices and no repro. Still happening to you? Do you have any browser extensions like AdBlock the might block it?

Comment: Hm; no browser extensions should lead to a 504 or any server-side errors, really. It seems like perhaps errors shouldn't be displayed there, but it's probably tricky to intercept and clean that up, since I'm assuming it's just content in an iframe (just a guess, don't feel like disabling adblock to find out). My gut says this might end up declined for that reason.

Comment: Refreshed and things were fine -- just seemed odd to see it.  No browser extensions that would block it.